# VB.NET Execute a form from a form with administrator username and password

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm hoping to run a form using administrator (domain) credentials by a standard user.

I don't think I can run a single form without first running it as administrator but I'm wondering if you can click a button on a form and that action could launch another form with admin credentials built-in.

Comment: Admin rights are per application, not form by form

Comment: Sorry - see, I really don't know much.  I'm guessing I meant application instead of form.  So could I run another application (form) from a button on a separate application (form)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I get some input on whether this will work?  I've pieced it together and haven't run it through any testing yet.  It looks like it's running a .bat file.  can this simply be changed to an exe??

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Security

'Password is a SecureString that needs to be built
Dim securePassword as New Security.SecureString()
For Each c As Char In userPassword
    securePassword.AppendChar(c)
Next c


Dim proc as ProcessStartInfo  = new ProcessStartInfo()
proc.FileName = "filelocation.bat"
proc.WorkingDirectory = "your_working_dir"
      proc.UseShellExecute = False
      proc.Domain = userDomain
      proc.UserName = userName
      proc.Password = securePassword
Process.Start(proc)
```

Comment: Don't pose a question in an answer. Either update your question above, or  create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ProcessStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("C:\path\to\app.exe")

With ProcessStartInfo
    ' The following properties run the new process as administrator
    .UseShellExecute = True
    .Verb = "runas"
    .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    .CreateNoWindow = False
End With

Try
    ' Start the new process
    Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)
Catch ex As Exception
    ' The user did not allow the application to run as administrator
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry, this application must be run as Administrator.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
End Try
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that is what I'm asking.  I need to be able to click a button on a form in an application and have that button start another application with administrator credentials built in.  I don't want the user to just click and go with out any requests for admin credentials or warnings.

Comment: Can I get some input on whether this will work?  I've pieced it together and haven't run it through any testing yet.  It looks like it's running a .bat file.  can this simply be changed to an exe?? `code`

Comment: The code I gave in my answer would go into your button click handler, and does exactly what you describe...the user **will** get asked to approve the elevated execution, if they decline, that's where my Try-Catch comes in...it throws that exception and that MessageBox, all within the app with the button they clicked.  Note that if the app you want to run is another instance of the same app, follow the Process.Start with an Application.Exit, which will only be reached if the user accepts the elevated run.